# Scheme: remove elements from nested list

Tags: list, scheme

Given a propositional formula, i. e. `((a and (b implies c) or (d and (e implies f))))`,
I need to write a Scheme function to remove the connectives, `and`, `implies`, `or`.
The the return of the function contains all variables in the formula. For instance, 
`(a b c d e f)`.

I am not sure how to even get started on this, because I am unsure how to get inside the nested lists and remove and `cons` certain variables and connectives.

Comment: How would look your formula like after removing one, two, or all connectives? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I would start up with something like the following:

```
(define somelist
  (list 'a 'and (list 'b 'implies 'c) 
        'or (list 'd 'and (list 'e 'implies 'f))))

(define (remove-vars xs ys)
  (let ((xs-f (flatten xs)))
    (filter-two xs-f ys)))

(define (filter-two xs ys)
  (foldr (lambda(y acc)
           (filter (lambda(x) (not (eq? x y))) acc))
         xs
         ys))
```

Test:

```
> (remove-vars somelist (list 'and 'or 'implies))
(a b c d e f)
> (remove-vars somelist (list 'and 'or))
(a b implies c d e implies f)
```

**UPDATE**: OK, @karategeek6 reported, that he doesn't have `flatten` and `filter` in his Scheme interpreter, and I'm not sure you do, so let's implement them manually, because there are no `filter` and `flatten` in R^6RS either:

```
(define (my-flatten xs)
  (foldr
   (lambda(x acc)
     (if (list? x)
         (append (my-flatten x) acc)
         (cons x acc)))
   (list)
   xs))

(define (my-filter pred xs)
  (let recur ((xs xs)
              (acc (list)))
    (if (empty? xs)
        (reverse acc)
        (if (pred (car xs))
            (recur (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) acc))
            (recur (cdr xs) acc)))))
```

Modify `remove-vars` and `filter-two` appropriately:

```
(define (remove-vars xs ys)
  (let ((xs-f (my-flatten xs)))
    (filter-two xs-f ys)))

(define (filter-two xs ys)
  (foldr (lambda(y acc)
           (my-filter (lambda(x) (not (eq? x y))) acc))
         xs
         ys))
```

You should get the same output as with previous versions of the above procedures.

Comment: Where do filter and flatten come from?  Are they new in the R6RS?  I'm currently only familiar with R5RS and I know they are not in that standard.

Comment: filter is from srfi-1, flatten ... i do not know.

Comment: And i would implement filter with fold, too.